# Fetch comment from specific user on a page post?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

With `FQL` being deprecated, is there an alternative `graph`-y way of fetching the post-comments from a specific user without resorting to downloading all comments first and enumerating them?

Before I could just trigger an FQL statement like

```
 SELECT text FROM comment 
 WHERE post_id = '<postid>' AND fromid = '<uid>'
```

But since that is no longer supported without using the older API, I'm wondering if there's an alternative for v2.1 and up?

Why? I organise a fair amount of give-away-contests on Facebook and have a script that retrieves the amount of likes from the announcement post, picks a number of random ones and then retrieves the comments of those users on that same post.

As a side remark: I hate it that I as a page owner cannot retrieve a list of people that liked my own page via the API. I still have to check that manually each time.

Comment: UNfortunately there isn't imho...

Comment: Tbh, that's what I'm afraid of. Been looking for a full day before I posted the question and have turned up zilch.

Comment: A bummer, I know... If you're using a v2.0 app, you can still use FQL until August 7th 2016. I'd wait and see if FB amends the Graph API with similar functionality as FQL had in the future

Comment: Indeed, it currently works with FQL Knowing that one day it'll stop working I wanted to be prepared. By then I probably won't know why anymore ;) 
If you would be so kind to formulate your comments as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way to filter the comments by user directly with the current Graph API version.

If you're using a v2.0 app, you can still use FQL until August 7th 2016. I'd wait and see if FB amends the Graph API with similar functionality as FQL had in the future.